# Manipulação de Atributos JAVA

Tags: java, interface, herança, atributos

Boa tarde, estou com um trabalho de faculdade e é o primeiro semestre que estou aprendendo java.

O trabalho basicamente é:

Fazer uma interface que representaria qualquer figura geometrica, nela especificar metodos de area e perimetro;

Fazer uma classe abstrata que representaria um quadrilatero qualquer e que recebe 4 atributos no construtor (x,y,z,w) e já implemento o metodo perimetro da interface.

Fazer uma classe retangulo, e possui apenas os atributos (base e altura) e herda tudo que tem na classe quadrilatero, que como citei possui implements da figura geometrica.

Estou com duvida justamente nesse trecho:

A classe pai recebe 4 atributos no construtor (x,y,z,w) e para os calculos de area e perimetro eu só preciso de 2 (base e altura), logo conversando com professor ele comentou alguma coisa de manipular os atributos para que a cada 2 fossem 1.
Ex: minha classe pai tem x,y,z,w como atributos;
A classe filha retangulo tem base, altura como atributos.
A ideia é que a filha associe base com x,y (nao tenho ideia de como, mas foi oque ele sugeriu) e a altura com z,w.

Segue o trecho de codigo do meu programa, só não reparem por que é bem iniciante ainda.

```
public interface FigGeometrica {
    double perimetro();
    double area();
    String nome();
}

//classe pai abstrata.
abstract class Quadrilateros implements FigGeometrica{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;
    public double w;

    public Quadrilateros(double x, double y, double z, double w) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.w = w;
    }

    public double perimetro(){
        return x+y+z+w;
    }
}

//Classe filha que herda Quadrilateros
public class Retangulo extends Quadrilateros{

    private String objNome;

    public Retangulo(String objNome, double x, double y, double z, double w){
        super(x, y, z, w);
        this.objNome = "Retangulo";
    }

    @Override
    public double perimetro(){
        return 2*super.x+2*super.y;
    }

    @Override
    public double area(){
        return super.x*super.y;
    }
```

Como podem ver o z e w vao aparecer no construtor, mas aqui eu não utilizaria para absolutamente nada. Eu quero fazer com que eu só peça o necessário no construtor só base / altura.

Alguem já utilizou sabe oque eu devo buscar para aprender e realizar essa manipulação?
Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Remova do construtor estes atributos, assim como você já o alterou adicionando objNome. Passe para super algo como (x, y, x, y), já que os dois lados são guais.

Comment: Boa tarde Murilo.
Cara o construtor você se refere ao da Classe Quadrilatero?
Ou você diz da classe retangulo?

Comment: Boa tarde, falo da classe Retangulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode atribuir os valores do X e Y para o Z e W, respectivamente, criando um construtor na classe Pai:

```
public Quadrilateros(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = x;
    this.w = y;
}
```

Chamando na classe retângulo como:

```
public Retangulo(String objNome, double x, double y){
    super(x, y);
    this.objNome = "Retangulo";
}
```

Dessa forma, na classe filha `Retangulo`, você pode apenas sobrescrever o método de cálculo de área:

```
@Override
public double area(){
    return super.x * super.y;
}
```

Comment: Realizei aqui, deu certo eu não tava entendendo oque acontecia neste trecho:
    public Retangulo(String objNome, double x, double y){
        super(x, y);